# build an object without using of "new"

Tags: javascript

How can this object be rewritten so you don't need to declare it with "new"?

```
var Lang = new function(){
    this.get = function(str, trans){
        if(TRANSLATE[str]){
            var str = TRANSLATE[str][LANG];
            if(count_obj(trans) > 0){
                for(var key in trans){
                    str = str.replace('%'+key+'%', trans[key]);
                }
            }
        }

        return str;
    };
};
```

To something like this:

```
var Lang = {
get : function(){}
};
```

Comment: What's wrong with your own solution using var Lang = { ... }?

Comment: hehe.. I didn't know it was just like that.. :D

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote the solution to your own question in the question...this is a perfectly valid way to create an object in javascript:

```
var Lang = {
    get: function(str, trans){
        if(TRANSLATE[str]){
            var str = TRANSLATE[str][LANG];
            if(count_obj(trans) > 0){
                for(var key in trans){
                    str = str.replace('%'+key+'%', trans[key]);
                }
            }
        }

        return str;
    };
};
```

If you want private variables, the usual way to do that is to create a function with local variables that return the object with those variables encapsulated in a closure like so:

```
var Lang = (function() {
    var p1; // private variable
    var p2; // another private variable

    return {
       getP1: function () {
          return p1;
       },
       setP1: function(value) {
          p1 = value;
       }
    };
})();
```

Note that the function that creates the object you want is executed right away and returns the object with two private variables captured in the closure. Those variables will not be accessible from outside the object.

Comment: ohh... but how can you then have private variables in the Lang object? if you want to put a "var private_var = 'something'" in the object?

Comment: updated the answer to include an example with private variables.

Answer (score 1):

**Patterns for Enforcing new**

As mentioned already, constructors are still just functions but invoked with new. 
What
happens if you forget new when you invoke a constructor? This is not going to cause
syntax or runtime errors but might lead to logical errors and unexpected behavior.
That’s because when you forget new, this inside the constructor will point to the global
object. (In browsers this will point to window.)

When your constructor has something like this.member and you invoke the constructor
without new, you’re actually creating a new property of the global object called
member and accessible through window.member or simply member. This behavior is highly
undesirable, because you know you should always strive for keeping the global namespace
clean.

```
// constructor
function Waffle() {
   this.tastes = "yummy";
}
// a new object
var good_morning = new Waffle();
console.log(typeof good_morning); // "object"
console.log(good_morning.tastes); // "yummy"
// antipattern:
// forgotten `new`
var good_morning = Waffle();
console.log(typeof good_morning); // "undefined"
console.log(window.tastes); // "yummy"
```

**Self-Invoking Constructor**

To address the drawback of the previous pattern and have prototype properties available
to the instance objects, consider the following approach. In the constructor you
check whether this is an instance of your constructor, and if not, the constructor invokes
itself again, this time properly with new:

```
function Waffle() {
   if (!(this instanceof Waffle)) {
      return new Waffle();
   }
   this.tastes = "yummy";
}
Waffle.prototype.wantAnother = true;
// testing invocations
var first = new Waffle(),
second = Waffle();
console.log(first.tastes); // "yummy"
console.log(second.tastes); // "yummy"
console.log(first.wantAnother); // true
console.log(second.wantAnother); // true
```

Another general-purpose way to check the instance is to compare with
arguments.callee instead of hard-coding the constructor name.

```
if (!(this instanceof arguments.callee)) {
   return new arguments.callee();
}
```

This pattern uses the fact that inside every function, an object called arguments is created
containing all parameters passed to the function when it was invoked. And arguments
has a property called callee, which points back to the function that was called. Be
aware that arguments.callee is not allowed in ES5’s strict mode, so it’s best if you limit
its future use and also remove any instances should you find them in existing code.

*“JavaScript Patterns, by Stoyan Stefanov (O’Reilly). Copyright 2010 Yahoo!, Inc., 9780596806750.”*

Answer (score 0):

just leave the "new" out, rest is the same. :)

```
var Lang = function(){ 
...
}
```

Edit: example copy-paste from firebug, "dsa" is just an object, "dsaFunc" is a function, but you can do the same with them:

```
>>> var dsa = {};
undefined
>>> dsa.get = function(a){ return a+1;}
function()
>>> dsa.get(2)
3
>>> var dsaFunc = function(){};
undefined
>>> dsaFunc.get = function(a){ return a+1;}
function()
>>> dsaFunc.get(2)
3
```

Comment: but then it won't be declared as an object but as a function

Comment: In javascript functions and objects are pretty much the same from a practical standpoint.

Comment: @Akos: this is NOT how you create javascript objects...see user278064's answer for why. Here's a simple test case for you var f = function() { this.abc = 10; }; f.abc will be undefined, where as if you actually used var f = new function() {this.abc = 10;}; f.abc will be 10 as you would expect.

Comment: user278064 indeed has a better explanation. As a side note: var f2 = {abc : 10}; seems to be the same as var f = new function() {this.abc = 10;};